# Where are the extra TBs of data coming from when I scan the disk?

Tags: macos, filesystem, apfs

I'm not a habitual Mac user.  I wanted to get a breakdown of disk usage on a Mac, so having installed `ncdu` via homebrew ages ago, I did `sudo ncdu -x /`.  Realising it would take forever, I installed `duc` with `brew install duc`, set it to profile with `sudo duc index -xpH /`.  (Flags: `-x` = don't cross filesystem boundaries, `-H` = count hardlinks once, `-p` = progress).  This morning this 120GB Mac had managed to scan as much as 2TB.  I killed the process and switched off WiFi, in case it had mounted the network drive, and tried again: same problem.  I gave up and went back to `ncdu`: same problem.  I accepted defeat and installed some graphical app which seems to do the job.

Question: where is all this data coming from?  I'm familiar with hardlinks being double counted, but both `duc` and `ncdu` can correct for that.  I've never seen behaviour like this on any Linux system; clearly, the Mac filesystem model is very different.  What's going on?

(I realise that part of what's going on is my naively trying to use Linux tools on a Mac.  I've corrected that.  But I want to know what's happening at the filesystem level because I've never seen this scale of a problem before: if you forget to exclude special paths in Linux you might get a few MB of nonsense (although most just fail); hardlinks can give you more than you wanted, but not by that order of magnitude.  Clearly, macOS exposes a very different underlying model.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What’s going in in a nutshell is “crawling the filesystem type tools” need to be updated for APFS in general and snapshots, [firm links specifically](https://www.swiftforensics.com/2019/10/macos-1015-volumes-firmlink-magic.html). Once that’s done, you’ll have a happier experience.

I would use those inside a user home folder and use a tool like Daisy Disk or the Apple disk space tools to locate files and allocations you don’t expect on a “system” basis.

Or you can dig into the [APFS volume groups](https://bombich.com/kb/ccc5/working-apfs-volume-groups) and learn when and where filesytem crawling tools can get caught in loops or dead ends or “worm holes” to other file systems ([including user created loops and synthetic firmlinks](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2020/01/18/creating-root-level-directories-and-symbolic-links-on-macos-catalina/)).

- https://eclecticlight.co/2021/01/13/big-sur-boot-volume-layout/

Comment: Oh goodness, it really *isn't* just unix... ta.  Some very neat things here like the overlay/sealed boot volume, but no wonder crawlers get horribly stuck in it.  That also explains why I've never noticed before---I've always worked in subdirs of ~.

Comment: That's a good way of putting it @2e0byo and consider that iOS / iPadOS are also not just unix - they're a massive user base of CPU hours running and running....